# Delphi XE4 TGrid how do I get the value of a cell in the row I double clicked?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm writing a FMX program in XE4 using the TGrid class. I want to extract the value from a particular column of the row I double clicked in a TGrid.  The grid was loaded with strings from a database table (using live binding).

For example, say the TGrid displays 5rows x 10columns, and I'm interested in the values in column 9.  If I double click anywhere in row 2, I want the value of cell(row=2, col=9) to be put in a TEdit.

I may be looking at things simplistically, but in TGrid I did not find any function that can get me a cell value based on its (row,col).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the protected method `GetValue`.

```
function GetValue(Col, Row: Integer): TValue; virtual;
```

Then using the `ColumnIndex` and `Selected` properties you can get the current col and row.

Try this

```
type 
  TGridClass=class(TGrid);

procedure TForm1.Grid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(TGridClass(Sender).GetValue(TGrid(Sender).ColumnIndex, TGrid(Sender).Selected).ToString);
end;
```

Comment: +1. I read the question shortly after it was posted, and thought "Rodrigo will be by with the answer, but I'll look anyway." and started trying to figure it out. I realized that the FMX implementation of `TGrid` is terrible (it's a **grid** - the need to  access a specific **cell** should be clear, and it shouldn't be so hard to do so, and a `TStringColumn` should give you access to the **string** it holds in a specific cell easily).

Comment: Thank you. What if the TGrid is already created by the Binding Wizard?  I was following some instructions on how to use dbExpress, and that's how I ended up with the TGrid.  My first mistake was probably chosing FMX as opposed to VCL. Is there any other way to drill down in a TGrid and get the value in a specific cell? My dream of cross-platform coding starts to have shades of nightmare :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use something like

```
Grid1.Columns[Col].Controls[Row]
```